# Function calls in smart contract from script and checking value of variables

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

I am currently using Brownie to learn smart contract and blockchain development. I am having trouble understanding how to call functions and check value of variables from smart contracts using python script. How would I be able to do this?

Below I have a contract `DutchAuction` where I have defined a function `bid()` which returns `'Hello world'` just for testing purposes that I am trying to call.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155Receiver.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";


contract DutchAuction {

    uint public startTime;
    uint public endTime;

    uint public price;
    uint public startPrice;
    
    address public assetOwner;


    constructor(uint _startPrice, uint _endTime) public {
        startTime = block.timestamp;
        price = _startPrice;
        startPrice = _startPrice;
        endTime = _endTime;
        assetOwner = msg.sender;
        
    }

    function bid() public returns (string calldata) {
        return 'hello world';

    }
    
}
```

Comment: How does your call look like at the moment and is there an error?

Comment: HI Mikko, I am getting the following error now which shows there is a compiling error. `TypeError: Data location can only be specified for array, struct or mapping types, but "calldata" was given.` This happened after I went back to my project and attempted to compile the contract before attempting to call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `string calldata` to `string memory` in your `bid()` function `returns` statement.

The string literal is loaded to memory (not to calldata) and then returned.

If you wanted to return `calldata`, you'd need to pass the value as calldata first:

```
function foo(string calldata _str) public pure returns (string calldata) {
    return _str;
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#data-location

Comment: Thanks for the help, makes much more sense now! Also I realised I did not have interface contract in my interface folder.